# Как узнать проинициализирована ли переменная Int или Bool?

Tags: java

У меня есть переменные, которые хранят определённые данные. В определённый момент, мне нужно отправить обновлённые данные и вот тут два варианта.

1. Если переменные содержат значения (от нуля и выше, `false` или `true`),
   то мне надо отправить эти данные.
2. Если этим переменным не были заданы значения (т.е. по сути, если они вообще не были проинициализированы), то я вообще ничего не передаю.

Для `String` всё проще. Там если `null`, значит данных нет. А вот для `Int` и `Bool` такого нет. С `Int` я ещё как-то могу выкрутиться, например изначально проинициализировать переменную значением -1, и потом проверять, если -1, то значит этой переменной не задавались значения.
 А вот с Булеановым значением сложнее. Там только `false` или `true`. Если же не делать проверку, то вылетает `NullPointer`.

Как быть? Можно ли как-то сделать проверку, чтобы знать были ли заданы переменной какие-то значения. В **swift** например, если значения не заданы, то там `nil`. И поэтому можно знать есть там что-то или нет.

Comment: Для примитива boolean только два значения,и false является дефолтным. Можете попробовать использовать Boolean. Все операции с ним будут прозрачны, тк будет автобоксинг и анбоксинг, но это уже объект и непроинициализированное значение будет null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для примитива `boolean` только два значения, и `false` является дефолтным. Можете попробовать использовать `Boolean`. Все операции с ним будут прозрачны, т.к. сработает автобоксинг и анбоксинг, но это уже ссылка на объект и если ей не присвоить значение и она является полем, то проинициализируется она значением  `null`

Comment: Терминология неправильная. В java нельзя прочитать значение переменной, если она не была инициализирована. Для полей класса есть инициализация значениями по умолчанию (`null`/`0`/`false`), для локальных переменных такого нет.

Comment: @Roman согласен, некорректно выразился, попробую по другому